# Power BI - Hide rows that have no value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI how do I hide lines with no values.
I assumed they are auto filtered out in Power BI as default.

I have searched the internet and not found a solution, have checked that 'Show items with no data' is not ticked.

As an example I want to hide the orange boxed lines below, is there a setting?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are showing because of your TY v LY % Variance measure. Get that to return blank when there is no data and your problem will be solved.